# How to cache multi-stage docker build in google cloud builder

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

I have docker multistage build, for example:

```
FROM golang:1.7.3
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/alexellis/href-counter/
RUN go get -d -v golang.org/x/net/html  
COPY app.go .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o app .

FROM alpine:latest  
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
WORKDIR /root/
COPY --from=0 /go/src/github.com/alexellis/href-counter/app .
CMD ["./app"]
```

Than I have cloudbuild.yml:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['pull', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/app:$BRANCH_NAME']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['pull', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/app:latest']
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: [
            'build',
            '--cache-from', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/app:latest',
            '--cache-from', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/app:$BRANCH_NAME',
            '--build-arg', 'COMMIT_HASH=$COMMIT_SHA',
            '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/app:$COMMIT_SHA',
            '-f', 'config/dockerfiles/app.dockerfile',
            '.'
        ]
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ["tag", "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/app:$COMMIT_SHA", "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/app:$BRANCH_NAME"]
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ["tag", "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/app:$COMMIT_SHA", "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/app:latest"]
images: [
  'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/app:$COMMIT_SHA',
  'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/app:$BRANCH_NAME',
  'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/app:latest'
]
```

Now I want to cache not only the resulting image but also the builder step. For example, in go I have /vendor which I construct using dep, and would like to cache those dependencies. How would I acchieve that the easiest with google cloud platform? I think my question is mostly docker specific, but still.

Comment: Did you check this page from our documentation? https://cloud.google.com/container-builder/docs/speeding-up-builds#using_a_cached_docker_image

Comment: I did, but how do you refer it? If you could provide end2end example I'd be more than happy

Comment: You should post this thread in the ServerFault, Stackoverflow is more suitable for developer concerns.

Comment: Ipp have you found any workaround? how did you do?

Comment: In the end, I've made secondary image which get's updated every time, and it's the builder image. (( That is first stage is separate docker file, second stage uses first stage with COPY --from <cache image name> ))

Answer (score 17):

The builder image needs to be build and tagged separately. You need to push that image from the build stage and use it in the next builds as cache. For that, is more convenient to name your build stage.

```
FROM golang:1.7.3 as builder
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/alexellis/href-counter/
RUN go get -d -v golang.org/x/net/html  
COPY app.go .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o app .

FROM alpine:latest  
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
WORKDIR /root/
COPY --from=builder /go/src/github.com/alexellis/href-counter/app .
CMD ["./app"]
```

In your `cloudbuild.yaml` you need to know which image you should pull to perform a better cache usage, and "store" that decision somewhere. I will show you how it can be done by storing in a file.

It's easier if you keep your logic in one build step:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
    - '-c'
    - |
      mkdir tmp
      (docker pull gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/app:$BRANCH_NAME && echo "$BRANCH_NAME" > tmp/base) ||
        echo "master" > tmp/base

      docker pull "us.gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/app-builder:$(cat tmp/base)" || true
      docker pull "us.gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/app:$(cat tmp/base)" || true

      docker build \
          --cache-from "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/app-builder:$(cat tmp/base)" \
          -t us.gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/app-builder:$BRANCH_NAME \
          -t us.gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/app-builder:$COMMIT_SHA \
          -t us.gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/app-builder:latest \
          --build-arg COMMIT_HASH=$COMMIT_SHA \
          -f config/dockerfiles/app.dockerfile \
          --target builder \
          .

      docker build \
          --cache-from "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/app-builder:$COMMIT_SHA" \
          --cache-from "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/app:$(cat tmp/base)" \
          -t us.gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/app:$BRANCH_NAME \
          -t us.gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/app:$COMMIT_SHA \
          -t us.gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/app:latest \
          --build-arg COMMIT_HASH=$COMMIT_SHA \
          -f config/dockerfiles/app.dockerfile \
          .
images: [
  'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/app-builder:$COMMIT_SHA',
  'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/app-builder:$BRANCH_NAME',
  'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/app-builder:latest',
  'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/app:$COMMIT_SHA',
  'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/app:$BRANCH_NAME',
  'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/app:latest'
]
```

The script creates the `tag` file inside `tmp/`, so it's important that this directory or file is ignored by Docker (put that on [`.dockerignore`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file)).

Notice that I avoided the use of `--cache-from` with two images. This is because in my experiments I was getting cache invalidation because the build was using the oldest image as cache. Also observe that the first `docker build` command has a [`--target`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#specifying-target-build-stage---target) argument. This is telling Docker to build only until the end of that stage.

I changed the default image to `master` because it guarantee that the base image is stable and is not in a branch too different from yours, which results in better performance. The `latest` tag is unnecessary in my example.

---

Answer (score 2):

Wanted to make an addition to @Philip's answer.
Google cloud actually runs your build steps in the `/workspace` directory.
On every build step, this volume is mounted again, meaning any files that exist in it can be accessed in upcoming build steps. 
So you don't need to make a `tmp` file or do everything in one step if that's what you prefer. 
Another note is if your build steps are long and require more complexity, I suggest you use the `script` key instead of `entrypoint` with `-c` 
Remember to pass all the required variables (including ready-made substitutions such as `PROJECT_ID` and `BRANCH_NAME`

```
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    env:
      - 'PROJECT_ID=$PROJECT_ID'
    script: |
            #!bin/bash
            <your script>
```

Or you could supply the shell script directly to the entrypoint parameter

```
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    env:
      - 'PROJECT_ID=$PROJECT_ID'
    entrypoint: /my_script.sh
```