# How to use cache in google cloud build with multi-stage Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile, google-cloud-build, docker-multi-stage-build

I'm trying to use a multi-stage Dockerfile in a google cloud build. I used the [speeding up build](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/optimize-builds/speeding-up-builds#using_a_cached_docker_image) documentation to create my cloudbuild.yaml.
The image is added correctly to my artifact registry but each time a new build is trigger everything is starting form the beginning apparently without using the cache.

Here's my Dockerfile :

```
# First stage
FROM node:lts-alpine as builder

COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
RUN mkdir /app-ui
RUN mv ./node_modules ./app-ui
WORKDIR /app-ui
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# Second stage
FROM nginx:alpine

COPY ./.nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.template
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
COPY --from=builder /app-ui/build /usr/share/nginx/html
ENV PORT $PORT
EXPOSE 8080

CMD sh -c "envsubst '\$PORT' < /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.template > /etc/nginx/nginx.conf && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
```

and here's my cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
  - id: pull-cache-image
    name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
    entrypoint: "bash"
    args: ["-c", "docker pull ${_IMAGE_NAME} || exit 0"]
  - id: build-container
    name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args: ["build", "-t", "${_IMAGE_NAME}", "--cache-from", "${_IMAGE_NAME}", "."]
  - id: push-to-registry
    name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
    args: ["push", "${_IMAGE_NAME}"]
  - id: deploy-to-cloud-run
    name: "gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk"
    entrypoint: gcloud
    args: [ "run", "deploy", "my-app", "--image", "${_IMAGE_NAME}" ]
images:
  - "${_IMAGE_NAME}"
substitutions:
  _IMAGE_NAME: "europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev/${PROJECT_ID}/my-repository/my-app:prod"
options:
  logging: CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY
  dynamic_substitutions: true
```

Comment: I took a look at it and apparently the only solution is using buildkit. Since my question I also found that in google cloud build there's a thing called Kaniko, I'll maybe try to use that.

Comment: You need to build the `builder` image first and `--cache-from` both the `builder` and your `${_IMAGE_NAME}` in a 2nd build. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52940692/1154847).